# When using FOR XML AUTO in SQL Server: how do I remove empty elements from nested elements when LEFT OUTER JOIN'ing

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005

[edit]: added RAW test and better sample code

I need to generate XML for a legacy application running SQL Server 2005, and I hope to use the `FOR XML` function.

I can not, however, seem to get rid of empty elements, when left outer join returns null.

I have created some test data below.

The result I get (AUTO):

```
<n id="1" Name="test1">
  <s SubName="sub1" />
  <s SubName="sub2" />
</n>
<n id="2" Name="test2">
  <s />
</n>
```

The result I get (RAW):

```
<row id="1" Name="test1" SubName="sub1" />
<row id="1" Name="test1" SubName="sub2" />
<row id="2" Name="test2" />
```

The result I want:

```
<n id="1" Name="test1">
  <s SubName="sub1" />
  <s SubName="sub2" />
</n>
<n id="2" Name="test2" />
```

Test code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#name') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #name END
SELECT * INTO #name FROM (
SELECT 1 id, 'test1' Name UNION ALL
SELECT 2 id, 'test2' Name )t

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#sub') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #sub END
SELECT * INTO #sub FROM (
SELECT 1 id, 'sub1' SubName UNION ALL
SELECT 1 id, 'sub2' SubName )t

SELECT n.id
     , n.Name
     , s.SubName 
FROM #name n
LEFT OUTER JOIN #sub s ON s.id = n.id
FOR XML AUTO

SELECT n.id
     , n.Name
     , s.SubName
FROM #name n
LEFT OUTER JOIN #sub s ON s.id = n.id
FOR XML RAW
```

Comment: Why does that empty `<s />` tag bother you?  Both your current and desired output should have the same semantic meaning (I think).

Comment: The XML parser in the legacy app does not handle this format, so I was hoping there was an option to exclude it.

Comment: This is a very elaborate question, +1 from my side!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Subqueries combine with PATH or RAW is the easy answer. Both can generate the desired result:

PATH:

```
SELECT n.id "@id"
     , n.Name "@Name"
     , (SELECT s.SubName "@SubName"
        FROM #sub s WHERE s.id = n.id
        FOR XML PATH('s'), TYPE
        ) 
FROM #name n
FOR XML PATH('n')
```

RAW:

```
SELECT n.id 
     , n.Name 
     , (SELECT s.SubName 
        FROM #sub s WHERE s.id = n.id
        FOR XML RAW('s'), TYPE
        ) 
FROM #name n
FOR XML RAW('n')
```

Comment: I just wanted to come up with exactly this. `FOR XML PATH` is the one and only form you should use... Other modes are good for the lazy ones, but `PATH` offers full control.

Answer (score 0):

@Kesse, check XML RAW

```
SELECT n.id
     , n.Name
     , s.SubName FROM #name n
LEFT OUTER JOIN #sub s ON s.id = n.id
FOR XML RAW
```

Comment: I believe I have simplified the sample code too much. When more rows exist in the #sub select, each row that has a matching id should be shown under the same root element. RAW seems to create an element for each. Also, it does not create sub-elements. I have amended the original question